# @Aggregation using SpEL in Spring Data MongoDB repository problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-el

I'm working on spring boot application with mongodb database, and I have a collection named DOCUMENT:
Here is the Document.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document("DOCUMENT")
public class Document {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private List<String> field1;
    private String field2;
    private Date field3;
    etc...
}
```

I have also a dedicated Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentRepository extends MongoRepository<Document, String> {

    @Aggregation(
            pipeline = {
                    "{ '$match': { " +
                        "?#{ [0] == null || [0].isEmpty() ? '' : 'field1 : { $in: [0] },' }" +
                        "?#{ T(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils).isBlank([1]) ? '' :             'field2 : { $regex: '.*' + [1] + '.*', $options: 'i' },' }" +
    "?#{ [2] == null ? '' : 'field3 : { $gte: [2] },' }" +
    "?#{ [2] == null ? '' : 'field3 : { $lte: [2] },' }" +
"} }"
            }
    )
    List<Document> findDocument(
            List<String> field1, String field2, Date field3LowerBound, Date Date field3UpperBound
    );

}
```

And in my service layer i call this method:

```
List<Document> documentList = documentRepository.findDocument(field1, field2, field3Lower,   field3Upper);
```

But i get this:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1096) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.JsonBuffer.read(JsonBuffer.java:50) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.JsonScanner.nextToken(JsonScanner.java:70) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.popToken(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:753) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:167) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679) ~[bson-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721) ~[bson-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:449) ~[bson-4.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:248) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:248) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:248) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:248) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
etc...
```

I change @Date lombok annotation to @Getter and @Setter, while debuggin i notice that it loops over hashcode but i'm not sure that is the problem

Comment: Enabling log debug the query is performed on DB? `logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb=DEBUG` I can't replicate the example because the provided pipeline example returns to me this error `SpelParseException: Expression [ [0] == null || [0].isEmpty() ? '' : 'field1' : { $in: [0] } ] @46: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'colon(:)'`

Could you check if the problem is the query creation itself or the amount of documents returned from query? This isn't a paginated query

Comment: @SalvatoreBernardo I have edited the question but I don't think that the problem came from SpEL format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem seems the SpEL itself, I replicated here https://github.com/sbernardo/spring-issues-examples/tree/main/sof-questions-77705053 and modified the SpEL as follow:

```java
public interface DocumentRepository extends MongoRepository<DocumentEntity, String> {

    @Aggregation(
            pipeline = {"""
                    {
                        '$match': {
                            $and: [
                                ?#{ [0] == null || [0].isEmpty() ? { _id: { $exists: true } } : { field1 : { $in: [0] } } },
                                ?#{ T(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils).isBlank([1]) ? { _id: { $exists: true } } : { field2 : { $regex: '.*' + [1] + '.*', $options: 'i' } } },
                                ?#{ [2] == null ? { _id: { $exists: true } } : { field3 : { $gte: [2] } } },
                                ?#{ [3] == null ? { _id: { $exists: true } } : { field3 : { $lte: [3] } } }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                    """
            }
    )
    List<DocumentEntity> findDocument(List<String> field1, String field2, Date field3LowerBound, Date field3UpperBound);

}
```

NOTE: I can't avoid to add parameter as described here, so I suggest to use a mandatory field instead of `{ _id: { $exists: true } }`

I found this issue in Spring Data Mongo to manage null values and the workaround is similar to my implementation. This the issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4050. Note the issue is for `@Query` but I think is the same.

I tried some cases and works as expected. Hope this will help. If you find a better solution I will want to know :D

Comment: Have you any idea why the $regex doesn't work correctly. I Have two documents :

{_id: ObjectId, field1: value1, field2: 'A'} {_id: ObjectId, field1: value1, field2: 'AB'}

And:

?#{ T(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils).isBlank([1]) ? { _id: { $exists: true } } : { field2 : { $regex: '.*AB.*', $options: 'i' } } } 

returns 0 documents.

Comment: Strange. I tried with regex and works as expected. Have you inserted other filters to aggregation? I tried your example in my repository and works fine. Do you have a complete code where can I reproduce? Can you print the query executed, just set this `logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb=DEBUG` and you will see something like `Executing aggregation` in your log